# Need to get the SQL Server "PRINT" value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I have a **SP** that Prints the results into **SQL Server**, but I need to use that value in **C#**.

Changing the `PRINT` to `SELECT` is not an option right now. I tried to `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` but that didn't work.

Does anybody know if it is possible to get the value of `PRINT` command in **SP** redirected to **C#**?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doXYZ
AS
BEGIN
   PRINT 'XYZ'
END
```

Now in **C#** I need to get the value 'XYZ'.... any ideas?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?  Straight up ADO.NET or some sort of an ORM?

Comment: just straight up ADO.NET. SqlConnection with a connectionString and then SQLcommand. USING(SqlConnetion con = new SqlConnection("Server=LOCALHOST; Database=XYZ; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"))

Comment: @Akram Shahda: really nice edit, makes the question much more readable, if I could upvote I would =).

Comment: @ROMANARMY: I am satisfied without a voteup ..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [`SqlConnection.InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event.

Comment: [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22252379/224976) with working code based on this answer

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [`SqlConnection.InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event like so:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace foo
{
    class bar
    {
        static public void ExecuteStoredProc()
        {
            var connectionString = "Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName";
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.YourStoredProcedure", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourParameterName", "YourParameterValue");

                connection.Open();
                // wire up an event handler to the connection.InfoMessage event
                connection.InfoMessage += connection_InfoMessage;
                var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();             
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        static void connection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            // this gets the print statements (maybe the error statements?)
            var outputFromStoredProcedure = e.Message;              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd much prefer a synchronous solution instead of having to handle an event in this case. To accomplish this, I simply converted the `PRINT` statement to a simple `SELECT 'XYZ' AS RetVal` and then processed the returned data's first row's first field's value.

Comment: Doesn't disposing an object without unwiring its events prevent the GC from cleaning it up, thus incurring a memory leak?