# Alternative of PRINT output from SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on an MVC app with a database where I have a lot of empty columns in each table. Now if a user dynamically adds a field on form I have to check that which column is completely empty(available) and then assign it to the user added field.

For that matter I searched and found the following SQL code and it works fine.

```
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)
DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name as colum FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'MyTableName'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL) BEGIN print ''' + @col + ''' end'
EXEC(@cmd)

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
```

It prints all columns in the given table having all empty rows. Now I want to get that list in my MVC Controller. Since it is printing the results so I cannot use SqlDataReader. So I found a method in answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749826/need-to-get-the-print-value-in-c-sharp). It gives me results one by one.

```
public ActionResult getList()
{
    SqlConnection con = DBHelperADO.GetConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); // query = sql code mentioned above
    con.Open();
    using (con)
    {
        con.InfoMessage += connection_InfoMessage;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
}

void connection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    var outputFromStoredProcedure = e.Message;
}
```

1. How to populate a List of all column names from the handler? (can't use session or static list)
2. I don't want to use Event Handler in MVC app so is there any better option? (may be any other SQL code to give me the required result or getting the PRINT output by some other method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED according to @AwaisMahmood suggestion

You can change the *print* sentence by a temp table and then return it
(I don't have checked the correct sintax for the quotes in the set @cmd... line, but you can get the idea)

```
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)
DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name as colum FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'MyTableName'

CREATE TABLE #EmptyFields {
    FieldName nvarchar(60)
}

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
 insert into #EmptyFields (FieldName) values (''' + @col + 
'')
' end'
EXEC(@cmd)

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo

select * from #EmptyTables
```

Then, in the client, you can use a datareader as usual to fill a `List<string>` or simmilar.

Comment: its giving an error on line that is inserting in temp table.. "Must declare table variable "@EmptyFields"."

Comment: update your answer. it should create a temp table instead of temp variable. it worked fine for temp table.

Comment: THANKS for answering