# SQL Server Throw and transactions

Tags: sql-server-2012

I fully get that throwing an error to the calling program for informational purposes is a strange thing, but working with what I'm given here, but I have the below code which I call from C#.

The error is thrown but the data isn't deleted. If I don't throw then the data is deleted. Given I have the deletions in a transaction why would the throw after cause the deletion to be rolled back which is what it seems it's doing.

```
IF (@action = 'D')
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
                DELETE FROM dbo.inv_detail WHERE inv_id = @inv_id;
                DELETE FROM dbo.inv_header WHERE inv_id = @inv_id;
            COMMIT TRAN

            --Returns an info message to indicate that the repository invoice has been deleted
            SET @InfoMessage = 'Number: ' + LTRIM(STR(@inv_ref_nbr)) + ' for Site: ' + LTRIM(STR(@site)) + ' has been deleted';
            THROW 50001, @InfoMessage, 1;
        END
```

This is wrapped inside a try/catch where the catch is:

```
BEGIN CATCH

        SELECT  @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
                @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
        -- information about the original error that caused
        -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,  -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState     -- State.
                   );
    END CATCH
```

Comment: `If I don't throw then the data is deleted.` won't that mean no error ?

Comment: Yes, they were using this to get details of the deletion back to the calling program. They weren't using it for real errors. I get the right thing to do is most likely an out param, but just curious on throw seemingly rolling back the deletion transaction above even though it's been committed.

Comment: you were always throwing error `THROW 50001, @InfoMessage, 1;`

Comment: Right, this is all wrapped in a try catch so if a real error happens in the deletion it'll hit that outer catch, but if no error happens I throw this info message saying all went well.

Comment: It sounds like you might be triggering error handling in some outer layer which is causing a rollback. Have you considered using `RAISERROR` to generate an error with an "information" severity (<= 10)? This will be ignored by the outer `TRY...CATCH`, and should also be ignored by any outer layers (depending on how they're coded). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx. `THROW` always raises an error with a severity of 16.

Comment: @EdHarper So here is the thing. It originally had this and it does delete the data, but the C# app never triggers it's try/catch and so I don't get the info message back in the C# app.

Comment: Not 100% sure about the terminology, but I think you should be able to read from the SQL Server error stream in C# whether or not an error is raised by a T-SQL batch. Alternatively, you could take the view that this kind of feedback is completely unnecessary; if the delete fails for any reason, SQL Server will raise a real error. No error = success

Comment: Yes, at this point it's not so much about how to get the job done but understanding why SQL Server is doing what it's doing and why after a committed transaction would throw cause that already committed transaction to rollback? How's that even possible?

Comment: There's probably an implicit transaction in the C# code which rolls back when it detects an error. When that transaction rolls back, everything inside it rolls back too; inner nested commits aren't actually committed until the outer transaction is committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inferring from the comments, the issue is caused because the calling C# code is executing your T-SQL inside a transaction. When an error is raised, the C# code automatically detects it and rolls back the whole transaction.

You mentioned that the original version of this code used `RAISERROR` to raise a low-severity error.
Errors with a severity <=10 are treated as information only and are ignored by SQL Server `TRY...CATCH` - and by inference, the C# database driver you're using respects this.

By contrast, `THROW` always raises an error with a severity of 16 - which is treated as an actual error, trapped by `TRY...CATCH`, and rethrown to C# - which triggers a rollback.

(Errors and `PRINT` messages are delivered to a SQL client on a different TDS stream from result sets. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749826/need-to-get-the-sql-server-print-value-in-c-sharp) for a way to read them. My guess would be that this is how the original programmer read the returned low-severity messages.)