# Call this procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I created a SQL Server database. I call this procedure to get the **last** page of my pagination and use this for my last page in pagination:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NUMPAG]
    (@pagenumber AS int = 1,
     @itensQTD AS int = 5)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pagtotal AS int

    SELECT @pagtotal = CEILING(CAST(COUNT(*) AS numeric(18, 2)) / CAST(@itensQTD AS numeric(18, 2))) 
    FROM ProdutoVenda;
 
    IF @pagenumber < 1
    BEGIN
        SET @pagenumber = 1
    END

    IF @pagenumber > @pagtotal
    BEGIN
        SET @pagenumber = @pagtotal
    END

    PRINT @pagtotal
END
```

```
public int UltimaPAG()
{
    var connectionString = "Data Source=" + Environment.MachineName + ";Initial Catalog=Projeto1;Integrated Security=True";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.NUMPAG", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pagenumber", 1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itensQTD", 5);

        connection.Open();

        connection.InfoMessage += connection_InfoMessage;
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        return result;
    }
}

static void connection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    var outputFromStoredProcedure = e.Message;
}
```

I'm trying to execute this procedure, but I don't know how, I tried to do it like the code above, but when I run the result comes out -1, and it was supposed to come out 3

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you have the opportunity, please have a look at an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) such as Entity Framework or Dapper. It's not a direct answer to your question but it will save you a lot of time

Comment: What are you expecting to see in `rd.GetInt32(0)`? The stored procedure doesn't return a result set. Perhaps you'd want to return `@pagtotal` as an OUTPUT parameter?

Comment: When I run the exec in the ssms itself, this procedure returns the value 3, I write exec NUMPAG, and it returns 3, but i don't know how i can do that in aps.net

Comment: How can I return @pagtotal as an OUTPUT?

Comment: "and it returns 3" no, it _prints_ "3", it doesn't _select_ 3. Very big difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to get the SQL Server "PRINT" value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749826/need-to-get-the-sql-server-print-value-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Where would I put the exec of my procedure according to this answer? If it's too simple, I'm sorry, I'm just starting programming

Comment: The answer from Tim Partridge in that link gives a full code example included the Stored Procedure call.  The accepted answer is very brief and does not provide a full source example.

Comment: i did it but when i run the result is coming out -1, 
and it was supposed out 3

Comment: In the latest code you shared, you are not adding any parameter to the command. And also after executing the command you are not reading the parameter value. the stored procedure is not returning any value also not changing any rows in the database hence `ExecuteNonQuery` will always return -1. check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/example-on-how-to-use-output-parameter-in-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I added the parameters and still result -1

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes and it will be fixed

1. Your SP does not return any results. Only the number `3` is printed:

[image]

-edit this line of sp:

```
 SELECT @pagtotal = CEILING(CAST(COUNT(*) AS numeric(18, 2)) / CAST(@itensQTD AS numeric(18, 2)))
```

to

```
set @pagtotal = CEILING(CAST(COUNT(*) AS numeric(18, 2)) / CAST(@itensQTD AS numeric(18, 2)))

select @pagtotal as pagtotal
```

then the result:

[image]

2. in your c# code `you should read the result Query`. As follows:

   ```
   public int UltimaPAG()
   {
        var connectionString = "Data Source=" + Environment.MachineName + ";Initial Catalog=Projeto1;Integrated Security=True";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.NUMPAG", connection))
        {
           command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pagenumber", 1);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itensQTD", 5);
           connection.Open();
           connection.InfoMessage += connection_InfoMessage;        
           using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
           {
              rdr.Read();
              var result = rdr["pagtotal"];
           }
           connection.Close();
           return result;
        }
   }


   static void connection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
         var outputFromStoredProcedure = e.Message;
    }
   ```